# UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents() on Apple Watch

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I can not use

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
```

in WatchKit Extension, I have error:

```
'sharedApplication()' is unavailable: Use view controller based solutions where appropriate instead.
```

Is there some alternative ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: No there isn't.

The long answer:

Please keep in mind that the extension is not executed on the watch but on your phone. So if you would call `UIApplication.sharedApplication()` it would return you the application of the extension on your phone, anyway! Everything you do inside your extension is stuff that manipulates the extension on your phone. The only exception from this are the WatchKit methods. And even they are basically calls that are converted into instructions that are send over bluetooth to tell the watch what to do. At no time you can write code that executes on the watch!

You have no control what so ever about what the watch does with the instructions you send to it. You are basically acting as a server talking to a client and you have no control over the client. You should send as little instructions as possible and once you send them, your task is done, the rest is up to the watch.

That being said, you should carefully plan your UI in a way that you do not need any calls that manipulate the event delivery. You should focus on simple 'if user taps x I do y' interaction.

Another thing to keep in mind is, that your extension can not communicate with your main iOS app. You can create a shared app group between your iOS app and your watch extension to share data between them, however you can not directly communicate with your app. If you want to use parts of your apps logic, extract the module in question into a framework (this has become very easy with Xcode 6) and use the framework in both, your app and your extension.

Comment: IS there anything which allows me to do this ? `'if user taps x I do y` from phone ?

Comment: As of my understanding, you can simply setup actions from a `WKInterfaceButton` to a `WKInterfaceController` in your storyboard.

Comment: We can listen to events in watch extension, but can this be delegated to main iOS app ?

Comment: No, you can not interact with your iOS app directly. I update my answer.

Comment: That's not true. You can use the `openParentApplication:reply:` method of the `WKInterfaceController` to open the main app and send some data to it directly, without creating an app group. This way, it's possible to make the containing app do something after the user taps a button on the watch. But I have to state that it's bad practice to do so. You should design your app in a way that requires the minimal amount of calls to such methods.